# set initial value to a drop down list that bound with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I created a DropDownList like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="psName" DataValueField="psName">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then i bounded it with Store Procedure like this:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:igroup9_test1ConnectionString %>" 
   SelectCommand="spGetProjectStatusList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The Store Procedure:

```
create proc spGetProjectStatusList

as

begin

select ProjStatus.psName
from ProjStatus

end
```

I want to set the initival value of the DropDownList using another Query Like this:

```
create proc spGetProjectStatus
(
@ProjectID int
)

as
begin
select ProjStatus.psName
from ProjStatus
where ProjStatus.psID=@ProjectID
end
```

How can I do This?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the DataBound event of the DropDownList.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
   DataTextField="psName" DataValueField="psName"
   OnDataBound="DropDownDataBound"
>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void DropDownDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set value here.
    //DropDownList1.SelectedItemIndex = 5; //this will show the 6th item
    var itm = DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("BONAP");
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(itm);
}
```

You've to work the exact index of the item in the dropdown list.

However, the better way to do this is to do it all in the db layer itself. But you can follow this model.

Say your stored proc could be written as follows:

```
create proc GetCustomersAndDefault
    @defaultid varchar(5) output
as
begin
    Select CustomerID, Companyname from Customers; -- for your dropdown list

    select @defaultid = customerid from Customers where CustomerID = "BONAP";
end
```

This need to be bound to your sqldatasource control as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="GetCustomersAndDefault" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
OnSelected="SqlDataSource1_Selected">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="defaultid" Type="String" Direction="Output" Size="5" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

...and your code behind will now look like:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string defaultvalue;
    protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", ""));
        //DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 5;
        var itm = DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(defaultvalue);
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(itm);

    }

    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        defaultvalue = e.Command.Parameters[0].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Further improvement: there can be another version where you don't even need to call `FindByValue` method. That means you have to have the logic of getting the index of the item you want in your SQL itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @shmulikhazan what is code you've written in there? Also I've updated the answer a bit.

Comment: i try exactlyy what you wrote:
//DropDownList1.SelectedItemIndex = 5;

Comment: ok now it is work . it was a small thing i forgot. 
Thank You!!

Comment: Improved the answer. Please check